# Как исправить непрерывное движение при использовании управления через UI элементы? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру на андроид, управление реализовал через свайпы, но когда я делаю свайп вправо/влево игрок непрерывно движется вправо/влево

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler
{
    public float speed; 
    public float jumpForce; 
    public float moveInput; 
    private Rigidbody2D rb; 

    public bool facingRight = true;

    public bool isGrounded;
    public Transform feetPos;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    public GameObject ground;

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

        if ((Mathf.Abs(eventData.delta.x)) > (Mathf.Abs(eventData.delta.y)))
        {
            if (eventData.delta.x > 0)
            {
                moveInput = 2;
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            }
            else
            {
                moveInput = -2;
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            }
            if (eventData.delta.x == 0)
            {
                moveInput = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (eventData.delta.y > 0 && isGrounded == true)
            {
                rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
    }

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`eventData.delta.x == 0` никогда не произойдёт. `0.0008`, `0.000045`, что угодно но не `0`.

```
float Neutral = 1; // радиус нейтралки
if (eventData.delta.magnitude > Neutral) {
    if ((Mathf.Abs(eventData.delta.x)) > (Mathf.Abs(eventData.delta.y))) {
        if (eventData.delta.x > 0)
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
        else
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);
    } else {
        if (eventData.delta.y > 0 && isGrounded == true)
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up*jumpForce;
    }
} else
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);
```

Comment: Не сработало игрок по прежнему продолжает непрерывно двигаться

Answer (score 0):

```
private Vector2 _firstPress;
private Vector2 _secondPress;
private Vector2 _currentSwipe;

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    _firstPress = new Vector2(eventData.position.x, eventData.position.y);
}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (_startPlatform.activeSelf)
        _startPlatform.SetActive(false);

    _secondPress = new Vector2(eventData.position.x, eventData.position.y);
    _currentSwipe = new Vector2(Mathf.Abs(_secondPress.x) - Mathf.Abs(_firstPress.x), Mathf.Abs(_secondPress.y) - Mathf.Abs(_firstPress.y));
    _currentSwipe.Normalize();

    if (IsAlive)
    {
        if (_currentSwipe.x != 0)
        {
            if (_currentSwipe.x < 0 && IsReadyLeft == true)
            {
                SwipeLeft();
            }
            else if (_currentSwipe.x > 0 && IsReadyRight == true)
            {
                SwipeRight();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
}

private void SwipeLeft()
{
    _playerRigidbody.AddForce(-_player.right * _force);
}

private void SwipeRight()
{
    _playerRigidbody.AddForce(_player.right * _force);
}
```

Comment: Наверное глупый вопрос, но стоит ли мне создать переменные используемые в этом скрипте?

Comment: @Брай извиняюсь, я скинул из своего скрипта свайпы. ну если не хочешь запариваться, то можешь создавать, только у меня есть поле _playerRigidbody его замени своим `rb`, ну или наоборот...

Comment: а что за переменная с именем _player?

Comment: @Брай ну я обращаюсь к вектору right, значит это Transform